# Terraform: How to get value of second public ip in module cloudposse ec2

Tags: terraform, cloudposse

How I can get value of second IP address from Terraform module EC2.

Module- https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ec2-instance

I've created instance EC2 with parameter `additional_ips_count = 1`. In this situation instance has create with two network interface and I need get value public IP address of second network interface.

Normally the module allows me to extract the value of public ip from the value of `public_ip`. For example, if I create a module called server, I can get the value of the public IP address from the first network interface using the value `module.server.public_ip` but how to do it for the second network created using a variable `additional_ips_count = 1`.

Comment: The module doesn't expose it in any way so your options are to fork the module to add the appropriate output yourself, drop the module altogether and either write your own or directly use the resources or raise a feature request on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse out the values for the value returned from the output module.multiple_ip.additional_eni_ids.

```
module "multiple_ip" {
  source                      = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ec2-instance.git?ref=master"
  ssh_key_pair                = var.key_name
  vpc_id                      = var.vpc_id
  security_groups             = [data.aws_security_group.this.id]
  subnet                      = data.aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  name                        = "multiple-ip"
  namespace                   = "eg"
  stage                       = "dev"
  additional_ips_count        = 1
  ebs_volume_count            = 2
  allowed_ports               = [22, 80, 443]
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
}

output "multiple_ip_additional_eni_ids" {
  value = module.multiple_ip.additional_eni_ids
}

output "z_additional_eni_public_ip" {
  value = values(module.multiple_ip.additional_eni_ids)[0]
}
```

This will return the ip want.

```
Outputs:

multiple_ip_additional_eni_ids = {
  "eni-0cc853fb9301b2bc8" = "100.20.97.243"
}
z_additional_eni_public_ip = 100.20.97.243
```